# Java. Statement execution in cycle

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I try to execute `INSERT` query in cycle:

```
String selectTableSQL = "SELECT * "
                      + "FROM testTable";

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

while (rs.next()) {
     String rangeName = rs.getString("RANGENAME");                
     insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO testTable2 "
                    + "VALUES ('" + rangeName + "')";

      try {
           stmt.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
           // do nothing             
      }
```

But after one iteration this cycle breaks. If I don't execute `INSERT` query and print `rangeName` to screen everything works perfectly (there are a lot of values, not only one). So the problem is in statement execution. How can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If this is not a contrived example did you consider using `INSERT INTO testTable2 SELECT RANGENAME FROM testTable`?

Comment: shyam, no, I can't. This is only a part of code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it does: you're using the same `stmt`
Create a new `stmt2` variable and use it inside loop without destroying the previous one.

Comment: +1. And think about using a `PreparedStatement` for the `INSERT`.

Comment: alfasin, so I should create `stmt2` in cycle?

Comment: @user3649515 it doesn't matter where you declare it, but yes you can declare and assign it inside the loop. Second, good point by Axel, use `PreparedStatement` for insert. See example here: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Answer (score 1):

First: Never do so

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
           // do nothing             
      }
```

Add a `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch block.

I think you get an exception when you do so. You may need a second statement variable.